# if statement - field to accept only letters

Tags: jquery, regex

**Situation**

I have a field which needs to only accept letters. An error pops up if there are numbers in `display_name` on submit, but if I enter `pat123`, it accepts it, which I don't want.

**Aim**

To warn the user if anything but letters have been entered into `display_name`, so no numbers and symbols. What expression do I need to use and how do I implement it into my code, so only letters are accepted in the field?

```js
var fieldNum = /^[0-9a]+$/;

var display_name = form.find('input[name="display_name"]').val();

if ((display_name.match(fieldNum))) {
  console.log('error');
}
```

```html
<input name="display_name" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: What expression do I use and how do I implement it into my code? So only letters are accepted in the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code/logic.

First, the regex - why `/^[0-9a]+$/`? What´s with the `a`?

Secondly - if your regex matches, you log an error. That regex only matches a string of just digits (or `a`'s).

What you want to do I believe is something like

```
var fieldNum = /^[a-z]+$/i;

var display_name = form.find('input[name="display_name"]').val();

if (!(display_name.match(fieldNum))) {
    console.log('error');
}
```

The regex is fixed and it checks if it doesn't match (`!`).

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```html
<input name="display_name" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');">
```

**EDIT:**

```js
$('.myclass').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var x = $(this);
    x.val(x.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'') ); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="display_name" class="myclass">
```

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer not to include it in the HTML if possible?

Comment: If the OP would like this to include capital letters you should use an expression like `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Important note: Any JavaScript solution like this won't actually **force** the user to enter letters only; they could easily bypass your checks, if they wanted to. If data integrity is a real concern, you need to perform some validation on the **server side**.

Comment: @TomLord There is server side validation. This is just for front end validation to let the user know they've made a mistake. Thank you for sharing the information though!

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott:- I have added the Jquery code for it. I would recommend not to show error for this as it would just irritate your user. Instead you can simply restrict them to enter only letters like above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```js
var myFunction = function (x) {
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(x.value)) {
    console.log('error')
  }
};
```

```html
<input name="display_name" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

The ^ character means that the regex only checks from the start of a string. This is why 123test behaves as you expect but test123 does not.

Try removing the ^ and it should work.